# What is the last index of a third-order tensor called?

Tags: matrices, terminology, tensors

In a third-order tensor I guess the first and second index would be called *row* and *column* respectively but is there a name for the third index?

Comment: Not that I know of - I would probably just say "$k^{th}$ upper/lower index".  Personally, if I had to deal with a tensor with more than two indices, I wouldn't write its components unless I absolutely had to :)

Comment: -1 Tensor is _not_ a matrix, so the question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with the downvote. We could give names to the indices, even in the nonsquare case, I don't see anything senseless with that. Sometimes, giving names does help intuition.

Comment: @Marek I disagree with you.  Often, students of physics or engineering learn that tensors are generalized matrices which transform according to certain rules.  From this perspective, conceptualizing the "first" two indices as "row" and "column" makes good sense, and is not IMO worthy of a downvote.

Comment: @Neal: I'm facing a programming problem so I have to use a name for the total number of "things" analogous to rows and columns. Currently I call it *matrices*.

Comment: @Giuseppe: I agree with your sentiment of giving names but I stand by what I said. If the question were reformulated so as to use the word matrix instead of tensor (since it moreover doesn't really involve tensors at all -- it's only a question on the terminology of generalized matrices), I will remove the downvote. But I'll leave it here precisely because I am not a fan of the engineering attitude of thinking about the tensor as a matrix (of course, you can treat tensors that way, but then, you can treat almost _anything_ that way, so that's not exactly a great argument..).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common name after row and column is *tube*, [according to Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22row+column+tube%22+tensor). More generally, one speaks of *fibers* of a tensor, enumerating them by *modes*. The illustration below is from the book [Nonnegative Matrix and Tensor Factorizations](http://books.google.com/books?id=KaxssMiWgswC) by Andrzej Cichocki, Rafal Zdunek, Anh Huy Phan, and Shun-ichi Amari, published by John Wiley & Sons in 2009 (I surely hope reproducing one illustration is fair use).

[image: fibers]

<sup>(And +1 to the question; it received one of the more unreasonable downvotes I've seen around here.)</sup>