# Is there a proper term to refer to something that can either be a row or a column of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, terminology

Let $A$ be a $m \times n$ matrix; if I label the rows as numbers, so that the sets of rows is

$$R=\{0,\dots,m-1\}$$

and the set of the columns is

$$C=\{m,\dots,m+n-1\}$$

and consider simply the set

$$S= R \cup C = \{0,\dots,m+n-1\},$$

what is the term that i can use to refer to $i \in S$ ? Up to now i am using "row/column", and I would like to know if there exists a more appropriate name.

Comment: Why not call it simply an *index*? And state somewhere that *index* means either row of column index...

Answer (score 1):

People working with tensors  from the applied perspective  speak of *fibers*:

- mode-1 fibers  are rows (or sometimes columns)
- mode-2 fibers are columns (or sometimes rows)
- mode-3 fibers are tubes (see [What is the last index of a third-order tensor called?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/284270/))
- ... I don't think they invented names for fibers of modes $n\ge 4$

So, using the term *fiber* for something that can be either a row or a column is consistent with the literature. But of course, you should define the term anyway.